# Is there any way to schedule a download on Epic Games Launcher?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

Sometimes I really need to schedule downloads to late at night, but I can't find a way to do this.  Is there a feature, and if there isn't is there a workaround?

Comment: One possible solution similar to @Joachim's answer is writing a macro using AutoHotKey and using Task Scheduler to run a batch script that runs the script, opens the Epic Games Launcher, and downloads what you need.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality for this.

You can set the program up to download, and, after it has started, exit the launcher.
Then create a task in Windows Task Scheduler:

[image: Windows Task Scheduler - Start a Program]

Trigger it at a specific time (when you usually stop using the PC), or when you start up the PC, so you only have to remember to restart your system when logging off for the night.

[image: Windows Task Scheduler - Task Trigger]

The rest of the steps are self-explanatory.

You can find Task Scheduler by searching for it in the Start Menu, or by pressing <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and running `taskschd. msc`.

Once started, it should automatically pick up the download where it left off (it's wise to make a test run before relying on it, though).

Comment: ya i am.  So Epic games will pause a download if you exit it?

Comment: @Millard If it doesn't, that's called malicious virus. Yes it'll pause.

Comment: ok, didn't know that. =)  Thnx for clarifying.

Comment: @Millard, please let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: I tried testing it but I got an issue.  The task manager said the shortcut had been changed or removed.  I believe this is because I had to rename the main folder the launcher was in because it had a space, which caused the task manager to think a large part of the path was meant to be an argument,  not a path.  Not sure how to rename the folder without causing issues.

Comment: However I did try it on a different .exe and it worked fine =)